# How to create 'blog' and new page in Fuel CMS with CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, fuelcms

I am just starting out with fuel CMS and Codeignitor. I'm looking for easy to read suggestions, references, tutorials, code snippets, *ANSWERS* etc for the 2 following questions below. (2-part Question)

**1.)** How do I access 'blog' functionality; I've read it is **built in** as a `/view/blog.php` but I don't see it; I've tried to create my own (in same directory) but it simply resolves as a static page (I created it from the dashboard) but it lacks any blog > post > get post functionality; like '`blogs`' do. I've read time over, like Wordpress and Drupal; Fuel has a '`blog`' template. There is none under '`layouts`' as well.

So, at this point, I wouldn't mind creating my own '`blog`' page - **Which leads to:**

**2.)** How do I create a new page *manually* in Fuel CMS, without the dashboard.

I've created an empty `.php` file in this directory per documentation:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\FUEL-CMS-master\fuel\application\views
```

I don't really need a custom `_variables/` with this -- so what am I missing. I've read I don't need to add / set a new `controller` with this type of page nor static pages. I also don't want to have to do anything with the controller if I don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter works on CMV Controller - Model - View so to create a simple page you need to create at least 2 files 1 controller and 1 view

if you are using CI 2.2 http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/overview/at_a_glance.html

if you are using CI 3 http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/at_a_glance.html

- first you need to create controller
- second create your view

create a file in application/controllhers/blog.php

```
<?php

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
      //you can acesse this http://example.com/blog/view/  
    }

    public function new($page = 'home')
    {
      //you can acesse this http://example.com/blog/new/   
    }


}
```

Comment: why did you include page = 'home'  what does that signify? also the above will be in the blog.php controller file and that's it? thanks!

Comment: if you wanna pass any arguments, you don't need to use that !

Comment: What would be the end URI / URL. I've created this Controller and even a static view sharing the same name 'blog.php' -- but when I navigate to my website.com/blog.php 404 resolves. I've also tried navigating to website.com/views/blog/ how do I do this?! +P